# Nodejs - Mocha, Chai: How to test an end point that passes control to multiple middleware functions by calling next

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I have an end point that passes control to multiple middleware functions by calling `next()` for example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', isRequestValid, saveUser, respond)

function isRequestValid(req, res, next) {
    // Do some stuff
    next();
}

function saveUser(req, res, next) {
    // Do more stuff
    next();
}

function respond(req, res, next) {
    // Do more stuff and send response
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

I'm can test the end point `/` using Chai and Mocha for example:

```
describe("Testing / end point", () => {
    it("Does it behave as expected", (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .post("/")
            .send(someData)
            .end((error, response) => {
                // Assertions
            });
    })
})
```

I'm kind of confused how to test the individual middleware functions `isRequestValid` and `saveUser` using Chai and Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your middleware, you should consider making them requirable (by exporting them), then test each of them with mocked request and response objects.

Assuming this is your *index.js* file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', isRequestValid, saveUser, respond)

function isRequestValid(req, res, next) {
    // Do some stuff
    next();
}

function saveUser(req, res, next) {
    // Do more stuff
    next();
}

function respond(req, res, next) {
    // Do more stuff and send response
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
module.exports.isRequestValid = isRequestValid;
```

And then:

```
const isRequestValid = require('./index.js').isRequestValid;
describe("Testing isRequestValid()", () => {
    it("Does it behave as expected", (done) => {
        const mockReq = {
            body: {<some data>}
        };
        const mockRes = {};
        isRequestValid(mockReq, mockRes, done);
    })
})
```

This may not work as is, but I think this could be one solution for you.

EDIT: Have a look at these projects for mocking express requests and responses easily

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-express-request
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-express-response